# How to use snapshotChanges() with firestore and ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic3, google-cloud-firestore, ionic4

Hi myfriends i have code in my ionic4 app to retrieve a data from firestore and i try this code to do that but it didn't show any of those data

i tryed use snapshotChanges() in my code but it's failed
and i also i want to retrieve id of documents how can i do this

my code is below here :

**news.page.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument} from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
export class FilmsPage implements OnInit {
  news: Observable<any[]>;
  constructor(public db: AngularFirestore, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.db.collection('123').snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
      return actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data();
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...data };
      });
    });
}
```

**news.page.html**

```
<ion-content padding>
        <ion-item *ngFor=" let count of news | async">
          <ion-button routerLink="/details/{{count.id}}">{{count.name}} -> id: {{count.id}}</ion-button>

</ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: You need to assign the result of the `snapShotChanges()` to your class `news` observable property. `this.news = this.db.collection('123').snapshotChanges().map(...`. Also you need to use `map()` within `pipe()` as it's a [pipeable operator](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md) if you are using RxJS 5.5+. `map` operator can be imported as `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';` as you should be importing operators for proper tree-shaking rather than static imports.

Comment: thanks friend that useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of issues currently with your implementation.

The first issues is that you need to assign the result of `this.db.collection('123').snapshotChanges()...` to your `news: Observable<any[]>` class property to be able to effectively use the `async` pipe in your template:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.news = this.db.collection('123').snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
    return actions.map(a => {
      const data = a.payload.doc.data();
      const id = a.payload.doc.id;
      return { id, ...data };
    });
});
```

The next issue depends on your version of RxJS. If your project is using RxJS 5.5+, you should use [pipeable operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md). This would involve updating your import of the `map` operator as well as updating how it's used with `snapshotChanges()`. Effectively it would just be moving `map()` inside `pipe()`:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

// ...

ngOnInit() {
  this.news = this.db.collection('123').snapshotChanges().pipe(
    map(actions => {
      return actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data();
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...data };
      });
    })
  );
});
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: thanks your solution is worked ,, but i have another question how can i show the content of the id news in details page ?? in the details.page.ts what the function can i show the content of id ??

Comment: I'd recommend to create a new question with complete details of the issue/goal to help resolve this that other issue. It's going to be a similar solution, but you will definitely get better support that way. If this answer resolved this issue, you should go ahead and mark as resolved.